# Get-ADUser within a specific AD group

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I'd like to get an AD user account via powershell within a specific group.

I will know the `GivenName` and `Surname` of the user I will be looking for, so `Get-ADUser` seems like a good function to use.

The issue is that we have a large number of users in the OU and I want to limit the scope of the search to one AD group and the groups under that one AD group.  As far as I can tell, the `SearchBase` parameter of `Get-ADUser` will only work for OUs and not for groups.

I'd like to do this as efficiently as possible (i.e. not get all the users in the group and search within those users).

Comment: What do you mean by "search within a specific group"? Do you want to check if the user is member of a particular group?

Comment: I want to search for a user by their GivenName and Surname but only if they are a member of a specific group.  I don't want to know what group they are in. I just want to only search within a specific group. I am trying to get their email address from AD -- so I want the user object.  If I search for 'John Smith' I will get lots of results in the entire domain, but there won't be duplicates within the group as it's much smaller.

Comment: If you want efficiency, do it several ways and time them, then choose the fastest approach. There's no way you can predict how the query algorithm optimizations that AD uses will affect your search time. Also, there's no way to get what you asked for, i.e. getting members of a set without getting the set first.

Answer (score 4):

You could use `Get-ADGroupMember` for enumerating the members of a group, and use that as input for `Get-ADUser`:

```
Get-ADGroupMember 'groupname' |
  Get-ADUser -Properties EmailAddress |
  Where-Object { $_.Surname -eq 'foo' -and $_.GivenName -eq 'bar' } |
  Select-Object -Expand EmailAddress
```

If the group contains not only user objects you need to filter the members by class first:

```
Get-ADGroupMember 'groupname' |
  Where-Object { $_.objectClass -eq 'user' } |
  Get-ADUser -Properties EmailAddress |
  Where-Object { $_.Surname -eq 'foo' -and $_.GivenName -eq 'bar' } |
  Select-Object -Expand EmailAddress
```

For unrolling nested groups you need a recursive function:

```
function Unroll-Group($group) {
  Get-ADGroupMember $group | ForEach-Object {
    $userOrGroup = $_
    switch ($_.objectClass) {
      'group' { Unroll-Group $userOrGroup }
      'user'  { Get-ADUser $userOrGroup -Property EmailAddress }
    }
  }
}

Unroll-Group 'groupname' |
  Where-Object { $_.Surname -eq 'foo' -and $_.GivenName -eq 'bar' } |
  Select-Object -Expand EmailAddress
```

Note that this approach won't work for a user's primary group.

Comment: Thanks Ansgar -- how can I do this if the the users are members of subgroups only?  That is, the group is a group of groups, and users are members of those sub groups.

Comment: For unrolling nested groups you need a recursive function. See updated answer.

Comment: Thanks - this saved me some time! I updated the last code block to put $_ into a variable before the switch statement, since $_ was returning "user" or "group" when I ran it.

Comment: The `Unroll-Group` function works well, but worth adding that `Get-ADGroupMember` has a `-Recursive` parameter, so I don't think the function is needed.